# PHP. Как прочитать эту строку, после конкретной запятой

Tags: php

Всем примет.
Плохо умею работать с файлами и их чтением.

Есть такой код, который выводит из файл найденную строку.
Как теперь ее можно прочитать после конкретной запятой. Например 2,4,7. Чтобы можно было конкретный участок внести в массив и дальше применять. Я пробовал эту строку и с \trim(fgetcsv($handle)[2]) и прочим. Но все ломается и не работает как надо.

Мой код:

```
$search = "$utm";
$lines = file('../billtx/payprebill.txt');
foreach($lines as $num_line => $line_value)
{
    if(strpos($line_value, $search) !== FALSE)    
    echo"$line_value<br>"; // ЗДЕСЬ ВСЕ РАБОТАЕТ И СТРОКА ВЫВОДИТСЯ.;
}
```

Comment: Функция explode() разбивает строку на массив по разделителю. Потом делайте с массивом что захотите.
https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.explode

Comment: Приведите пример данных в исходном файле и в переменной $search, а то ничего не понятно